# Show UL element based on array value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

If i dump auth_user, I have an array of modules like this `[{id:1, name:'item-employee'},{id:2, name:'item-manager'}]`

I want to check to see if the auth_user modules contain item-employee specifically, and if so, I want to show a limited  element. Otherwise, I want to show more option.

I'm trying this but it still shows all 3 nav items even though my user object has the module that should limit it.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
    <ul v-if="auth_user.modules.includes(item-employee)" class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill" role="tablist" id="Item-tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#dailyList" role="tab" aria-controls="dailyList" aria-selected="true">Daily Item List</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul v-else class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill" role="tablist" id="Item-tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#dailyList" role="tab" aria-controls="dailyList" aria-selected="true">Daily Item List</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#calendarView" role="tab" aria-controls="calendarView" aria-selected="false">Calendar</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a  class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#userView" role="tab" aria-controls="userView" aria-selected="false">Users</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid this line does not evaluate to the right (desired) value.

```
.includes(item-employee)
```

I would do the filtering on a `computed` property. Something like:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      auth_user: {
        modules: [
          // ...
        ]
      }
    }
  },

  computed: {
    modules() {
      return this.auth_user.modules.filter(this.moduleFilter);
    }
  },

  methods: {
    moduleFilter(item) {
      if (item.name === 'item-employee') {
        return false
      }
      else if (your_other_filter) {
        // ...
      }

      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

### Edit

If you simply need to filter them inline in the template,

```js
methods: {
  checkModule(auth_user) {
    return auth_user.modules.some(item => item.name === 'item-employee');
  }
}
```

And in the template,

```html
<ul v-if="checkModule(auth_user)" class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill" role="tablist" id="Item-tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#dailyList" role="tab" aria-controls="dailyList" aria-selected="true">Daily Item List</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul v-else ...
```

Comment: So what would I do in the html portion in that case?

Comment: You would simply use the `modules` array in the template and no need worry about the filtering. Although that actually depends on whether or not you are looping the modules in a `v-for` ?

Comment: I'm not looping them at all, I just started with this as a way to simply show certain links only to someone with that module

Comment: Done. The key is we need to check the `name` property of the individual `auth_user.modules`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the find method. A sample is shown below. It will print user1 has employees and user2 has no employees

```
<html>
    <title>
        <head>Hello World</head>
    </title>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <h1 v-if="user1.modules.find(module => module.name === 'item-employee')">user1 has employees</h1>
            <h1 v-else>user1 has no employees</h1>
            <h1 v-if="user2.modules.find(module => module.name === 'item-employee')">user2 has employees</h1>
            <h1 v-else>user2 has no employees</h1>
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
        <script>
                var app = new Vue({
                el: '#app',
                data: {
                  user1: {
                      modules: [{id:1, name:'item-employee'},{id:2, name:'item-manager'}]
                  },
                  user2: {
                      modules: [{id:1, name:'item-manager'},{id:2, name:'item-manager'}]
                  }
                }
              })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```